# Nginx ingress results in redirect of login and 'invalid token specified error'

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have the following setup in Kubernetes:

1. Front-end Angular application (connected to Keycloak)
2. Keycloak for authorisation/authentication
3. Back-end service in Spring Webflux (connected to Keycloak)

The problem I am facing is: when I login to the Angular application (while running everything local, except Keycloak), everything works fine. However when I connect from the Angular app (weather local or deployed on kubernetes) to the Back-end Spring webflux service behind the Nginx ingress (depoloyed on kubernetes) I get redirected to the keycloak login page with the error: **Invalid token specificied** and **token successfully revoked**.

Here is my Nginx ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress-prd
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://auth.xxxxx.com, https://001.xxxxxx.com, http://localhost:4200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:

  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mainservice.xxxxxxx.com
    secretName: mainservice-com-06-01-2021
  rules:
  - host: mainservice.xxxxxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /*
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: main-service-prd
              port:
                number: 80
```

I have been struggling on this for days and playing around with settings for the Nginx ingress, but have not been successfully in getting this fixed. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What flow do you use to protect the apps with Keycloak? Does your Angular application obtain a token without the need to use the backend and then that token is valid even to call the backend.. or does the backend exchange the client secret for the token?

Comment: Also, in the case that your frontend obtains the token but then backend requests fails, maybe the token is too big? It may be if it contains too much roles. The Nginx controller has a configurable limit on the permitted size of the headers of requests. Check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers

Comment: The Angular app authorises with keycloak and uses the token to call the mainservice (as in example on top). I just did an experiment: when I run the mainservice local, I see that keycloak login through the angular app there is a user ID, however when I do that through mainservice in kubernetes user id is null and event is: REVOKE_GRANT_ERROR.

Comment: On another note: calling mainservice directly from Postman with a bearer token seems to be working, only in Angular it raises errors and I am not able to login through Angular with code flow.

Comment: Are Web Origins and Valid Redirect URIs configured in the client used by the Angular frontend? Maybe it works from localhost but not when you host it on Kubernetes because the hostname / uri at which your browser is pointing at changes.

Comment: They are configured correctly. In the scenario where I have Angular from localhost and mainservice in kubernetes. Web origins is set to * and Valid Redirect URI's is set to http://localhost:4200. If I point from Angular to mainservice local it all goes well, if I point to mainservice kubernetes the error arises

Comment: This is the message I see in Keycloak: 19:28:59,891 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-48) type=REVOKE_GRANT_ERROR, realmId=xxxxxxxx, clientId=xxxxxx-gui, userId=null, ipAddress=10.x.x.x, error=user_session_not_found, client_auth_method=client-secret

Comment: Did you install a library certified by OpenID? Also, when you connect from the angular app to Back-end Spring Webflux using the deployment on kubernetes, the logs in GKE show you any kind of error message?